# Get parent Paragraph Entity from Referenced View

Tags: views

I have a custom paragraph type - which has 2 fields:

- `Display Mode`,
- `View` to be rendered

I want to let users choose `Display Mode` in this paragraph, then I will render `view` dynamically based on this `Display Mode` value.

The problem is, it seems there is no way to get this `Display Mode` value inside view template(`views-view-unformatted.html.twig`) or hook (`HOOK_preprocess_views_view`).

Only what I can access is `view object`, which definitely does not have any parent entity info.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

All entities (*) in Drupal are meant to be stand-alone and self-contained, so do it the other way round: Instead of querying upwards from the view, pass the field value downwards from the paragraph template to the view as a parameter.

E.g. create a `paragraph.html.twig` template and then call the view with the paramater from your paragraph field (using the [Twig Tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)):

```
{{ drupal_view('my_view_id', paragraph.field_display_mode.0.value) }}
```

The first parameter of `drupal_view` is the machine name of the view, the 2nd parameter is the machine name of the display in that view.

(*) Paragraphs is kind of an exception as it is by data-model explicitly designed to be directly depending on a parent entity.

Comment: Simply not working with this error : Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "drupal_view" function.

Comment: `{{ drupal_view() }}` is part of the twig tweak module I've linked in my answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need [Viewsreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference). With this you just need 1 field on the paragraph, the viewsreference field, which provides a widget to select the view (autocomplete, or select) and the display ID, as well as it lets you limit to pre-defined list of views, and display types.